# Interface trava ao rodar o while utilizando from kivy.app

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou estudando processamento de imagem utilizando Python.

Fiz uma interface com `Kivy.app`, mas está travando quando executa o `while`. Estou utilizando o código abaixo para preencher uma matriz com "0" ou "1", fazendo com que a imagem fique *binarizada*.

Alguma dica de como resolver a questão de não travar?

Obs. Na IDLE do Python roda perfeitamente.

Código:

```
i = 0
        while i < (hs-1):
              j=0
              while j < (ws-1):
                    j = j+1
              if (lum_img2[i,j]) <= threshold2:
                      lum_img2[i,j] = 0
              else:
                      lum_img2[i,j]= 1
        i = i + 1
        i = 0
```

Comment: Estão faltando mais detalhes do seu problema. Em que parte da aplicação (*kivy*) está inserindo esse código? Se possível reescreva a questão fornecendo mais detalhes.

Comment: E o código está mal indentado, não tem como saber se está certo ou não. Se o `i = i+1` está fora do `while`, como foi postado na pergunta, o *loop* será infinito, pois sempre `i < hs-1`.

Comment: Anderson, muito obrigado pela rapidez na resposta.... realmente a indentação do 1 =i+1 estava errada.